# PHPStorm disregards the @deprecated comment

Tags: php, phpstorm

I deprecated a method in my project by adding @deprecated to the docBlock, expecting PHPStorm to pick that up when addressing that specific method. *My* PHPStorm, however, seems to disregard the comment and doesn't mark usages of that method as deprecated.

Now **I** do know that usage of this method is no longer allowed, but some of my colleagues may not. I just checked at someone else's computer and he's getting the deprecation warning, so it might not be a problem for everyone. I can't guarantee that though.

I invalidated the caches, rebooted PHPStorm, removed and re-added the @deprecated, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oops, found it...

For some reason my settings were changed/set back to default and the 'error when deprecated' setting was turned off.

Settings -> Inspections -> PHP -> General -> Deprecated -> As error